# Create column based on the comparative match between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe A which has a column called `A['Income']` and another dataframe B which has columns -  `B['Income']` and `B['category']`. I need to compare `A['Income']` with `B['Income']` and create A`['category']` such that,
when `A['Income'] <= B['Income']` then `A['category']` takes corresponding value of `B['category']`. and if `A['Income'] > 1000` then `A['category'] = 0.1`

```
A:
Income
1000
1234
3007
4569
7065
1456
2980
8990
900
489

B:
Income   category
1000      1.1
2500      1.2
4000      1.3
5500      1.4
7000      2.1
8500      2.2

Desired output: 
A:
    Income   category
    1000      1.1
    1234      1.1
    3007      1.2
    4569      1.4
    7065      2.2
    1456      1.1
    2980      1.3
    6450      2.1    
    900       0.1
    489       0.1
```

Below is what I am attempting but I just am not able to develop the logic of assigning the corresponding value to a new column. It is a dictionary like mapping, but without perfect equality and a range needs to be defined.

```
for e in A.Income:
print(e)
l=[]    
for j,k in zip(B.Income, B.category):
    if e<=j:
        l.append(k)
    else:
        pass
p.append(B[B['Income']==l[0]].category.values)

brack=list(chain.from_iterable(p))
A['category']=brack
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `merge_asof`

```
df=pd.merge_asof(A.sort_values('Income'),B,on='Income').fillna(0.1)
   Income  category
0     489       0.1
1     900       0.1
2    1000       1.1
3    1234       1.1
4    1456       1.1
5    2980       1.2
6    3007       1.2
7    4569       1.3
8    7065       2.1
9    8990       2.2
```

Update to match the output

```
s=pd.merge_asof(A.reset_index().sort_values('Income'),B,on='Income',direction='forward').\
   dropna().set_index('index').sort_index()
s.loc[s.Income<1000,'category']=0.1
s
       Income  category
index                  
0        1000       1.1
1        1234       1.2
2        3007       1.3
3        4569       1.4
4        7065       2.2
5        1456       1.2
6        2980       1.3
8         900       0.1
9         489       0.1
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know that method existed.

Comment: wowww.. merge_asof.. that is a wonderful solution, never knew of it! thanks so much!!

Comment: @YOBEN_S I believe you need to set the direction parameter to `nearest` and then replace the categories on <1000, as `4569` went the wrong direction.